# Hailstone recursion not working in Java

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion

I am trying to write a simple Java program to compute a hailstone sequence using recursion.  A hailstone sequence is basically: take a given integer n - if even, the next integer in the sequence is n/2, if odd, the next integer in sequence is n * 3 + 1.  I'm trying to return a string with each number separated by a comma, but my algorithm isn't working.  Can someone explain why?  Thanks!

```
public static String recursion (int n) {

    String s = "";

    if (n != 1) {
        if (n % 2 == 0) return s + String.valueOf(recursion(n / 2)) + ", ";
        else return s + String.valueOf(recursion((3 * n) + 1)) + ", ";
    }
    else return s + String.valueOf(1);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(recursion(435));
}
```

Comment: what is not working? is there some exception? do you get wrong result?

Comment: It's printing out just the number 1 with a bunch of commas.  So like:

1, , , , , , , , , ,

Comment: what should be the first number in sequence? n?

Comment: The first number should be n, yes.

Comment: it this your desired output? 435, 1306, 653, 1960, 980, 490, 245, 736, 368, 184, 92, 46, 23, 70, 35, 106, 53, 160, 80, 40, 20, 10, 5, 16, 8, 4, 2, 1

Comment: Yup! May I ask what you changed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the problem is, you don't print the actual number `n`. Change your code to:

```
public static String recursion (int n) {
    //set s to the number n
    String s = "" + n;

    if (n != 1) {
        //change position of the separator
        if (n % 2 == 0) return s + ", " + recursion(n / 2);
        //change position of the separator
        else return s + ", " + recursion((3 * n) + 1);
    }
    else return s;
}
```

EDIT:
btw. you don't need `String.valueOf()`, since the result is already a `String`

Comment: @ThurmanSteele if you think the answer is useful then accept and upvote (if possible) instead of putting thanks in the comment.

Comment: @ThurmanSteele if you plan to use it for large numbers, you should take a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization to avoid stack overflows.